# Antd, ReactJs, Routing and Component rendering issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

I have an issue with a project I'm working on.
I tried to implement "dynamic" routing and rendering of components, but it seems to just not work.

I have added a sandbox link containing some of the routes and basic components along with the structure I was going for.

It seems as if I hard code the routes and components to render, everything works, but when I use the  component that accepts the component, it won't render. I am not sure why.

I would appreciate any help or insight anyone is willing to give.

[Edit on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-trigger-antd-4-16-11-forked-wcg5d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)